# node-inspector fails to connect to node

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I run node with

```
node --debug app
OR
node --debug-brk app
```

it responds

```
debugger listening on port 5858
Express server listening on port 1338
```

I now start node-inspector

```
node-inspector --web-port=5859
```

It responds with

```
Node Inspector v0.3.2
info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:5859/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

Open chrome and go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:5859/debug?port=5858
```

Console logs the following

[image]

Using TCPview, it shows node is listening to port 5858 but it has no established connection.
When the connection is attempted this message appears on the node console

```
}Content-Length: 108
```

Nothing else.
I then tried to get the debugger to run on a different port:

```
node --debug=5000 app
node-inspector --debug-port=5000 --web-port=5859
```

but node-inspector would not connect
EDIT:
Well the error is not with node. I installed the Eclipse node environment and was able to debug. Decided to give node-inspector the benefit of the doubt and reinstall.

```
npm uninstall node-inspector
npm WARN uninstall not installed in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules: "node-inspector"
```

re-installed node
re-installed chrome
No luck same problem.

So Eclipse it is.

Comment: can you try again with `node --debug-brk app`? Are you sure that you are not attaching console debugger with `node debug app`? (e.i `debug` instead of `--debug`)

Comment: Sorry Andrey didn't help

Comment: you might have other debugger running somewhere. Try 'killall node' and restart your app with '--debug-brk'

Comment: What happens when you run `node debug localhost:5858` instead of node inspector? Can the node's CLI debugger connect to your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first attempt, you're telling node-inspector to try to connect to the debugger on 5859 (not default), then telling node debugger to listen on the default 5858.

Start node: `node --debug-brk app.js` and it will run the debugger on 5858.

Start node-inspector: `node-inspector` and it will try to connect to 5858.

Open your browser to the provided url to access the web interface and the browser should load up the sources panel and execution should be halted on the very first line of your app.

In your second attempt, your approach looks okay, and having used node-inspector for a year (presently struggling with 0.12.3), I'd say it was likely node-inspector causing the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

This are some steps may help you.

- Try to visit `chrome`.
- Open New Tab
- Type `chrome://inspect`
- This will open a Window, where you find the `Remote Target #LOCALHOST`
- You will find your node file name below `target` header.
- Click the link, This will open a debugger window for you.

That's It. Happy debugging. :)