# debugging node.js with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I'm trying to debug my nodejs app using node-inspector. But Google Chrome doesn't show the code.

I'm using the following,

Node.js : v0.10.26

Express : 4.0.0

Node Inspector : v0.7.3

Google Chrome version : 34.0.1847.131

This is what I'm doing to start the debugger..

```
$ node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.7.3
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

In another console,

```
$ node --debug app.js 
debugger listening on port 5858
$
```

Then started Google Chrome and went to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

It opens up node-inspector but without any code..all windows are empty.

Noticed that I'm not getting 'Express server listening on port 3000'

Tried all as per [node-inspector fails to connect to node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710548/node-inspector-fails-to-connect-to-node) but no luck

Couldn't work out what I'm missing. Would be great of you have any suggestions..so I can debug my Node.js apps in Google Chrome.

Comment: 1. Try to run node-inspector with --no-preload option.

Comment: 2. Check Chrome's DevTools console - are there any errors?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try to run `node --debug-brk app.js` instead of just `--debug`. Your application may not be pausing before node inspector hooks into the node process. Using `--debug-brk` will force node to break on the first line of your app and wait for a debugger to attach to the process. Loading the node-inspector web interface is what causes node-inspector to attach to your node process; that's why you include the node debug port in the query string (localhost:8080/debug?port=5858). You're telling node-inspector what port it should reach out and attach to.

Here's an animated gif I put together showing a complete install and run of node-inspector.

[image]

In the gif I use the `--debug` flag because I'm not debugging any code that runs right at startup. I'm debugging inside a request handler, which only fires when the page is requested. Thus, refreshing the page causes node-inspector to break on that line.

I also put together a 15 minute YouTube tutorial a while ago.

http://youtu.be/03qGA-GJXjI

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did check your youtube video before..very informative thanks. --debug-brk did the trick for me..however..when I put a breakpoint in one of my routes. In my case, I'm experimenting with cheerio + request to scrape a website. I've created a route, lets say scrape.js Im hoping to debug this file..but its not hitting the breakpoint..am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's hard to know without a code sample. Can you paste all the code that runs up to the point where that route is declared in a [gist](http://gist.github.com) along with the URL you're navigating to to trigger the request handler?

Comment: @AlexFord: How did you manage to create this gif? I think its really cool & can be very helpful

Comment: @SharpCoder I used [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) to record a video. In their advanced export options you can choose animated gif.

Comment: I want to invoke mocha unit test along with node-debug " >node-debug -p 8900 mocha . " , but facing similar problem, if we try to invoke node-debug with mocha, how to put -brk switch as we don't get handle on node

Comment: @SutikshanDubey refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15884692/498624). When you get to step 3 make sure you are using the `node-inspector` command and ***not*** the `node-debug` command. The `node-debug` command both runs your script *and* starts up the node-inspector server. You just want to start the server, not start your script. Then you can start your script separately using the `--debug-brk` flag.

Answer (score 22):

node-inspector by default tries to pre-load all the code before initiating the debug window. I have had instances, node-inspector just hangs for ever because of this pre-loading. Luckily the newer versions have an option to stop the pre-load thereby making the inspector load faster.

Try `node-inspector --no-preload`

Comment: Very helpful! I too have had this stupid hanging problem when I'd rather just hit breakpoints right away. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

Standard remote debugging is broken entirely in node 6.5. It's replaced however by a new internal node feature

```
$ node --inspect --debug-brk build/server/server.js
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@62cd277117e6f8ec53e31b1be58290a6f7ab42ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node
Debugger attached.
```

See here - http://arveknudsen.com/?p=346%3Fpage_id%3D346&print=pdf - for more info

Comment: You just saved my day! No need for node-inspector anymore.

Comment: hmm, in my case it's giving me a URL starting with "ws://" ... the machine is a headless server, so I passed the host:port option, yet I still can't open the "ws://" URL in my local instance of Chrome

Answer (score 1):

`--debug-brk` is now deprecated

try `node --inspect-brk <your starting file name>` 
and then go to chrome and type url
`chrome://inspect` and click on `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`,
the debugger will start, no need of node-inspector

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On the left of Node Inspector, "Sources" tab, there is "a box with a triangle in it" - highlighting says "Show Navigator". (See it in the picture above). Open that to find the files you want to debug, and put a break point on code that has yet to run.

Also note, if you want to debug code that runs on starting node, you'll need to use the `--debug-brk` option when starting. Then, in Node Inspector, you you'll have to kick off the app (`F8` to run all). You'll need this option if you want to debug all the initialization code, like starting a web browser.

Comment: Thanks Clay, --debug-brk seem to have worked..it did't work initially though..but after trying few times..it did..

Answer (score 0):

`node-debug --no-preload app.js`

This what's working for me. According to [this](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#my-script-runs-too-fast-to-attach-the-debugger):

> My script runs too fast to attach the debugger.
>
> The debugged process must be started with --debug-brk, this way the
> script is paused on the first line.
>
> Note: node-debug adds this option for you by default.