# How to use node-inspector with ember

Tags: node.js, ember.js, node-inspector

I'm using emberjs on client + nodejs on server and I would like to use node-inspector for debugging server side. Maybe someone know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to google this question?

Comment: Yes, sure, but nothing found.

Comment: If you change your question to `node-inspector for debugging nodejs` you will have better luck. This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340968/debugging-node-js-with-node-inspector

Comment: but I'm using emberjs)