# Debug server-side code with readline module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Javascript and Node.js.

Coming from C# I want to debug something like this with breakpoints set in Debugging-console:

```
var name = Console.readline();
Console.Writeline(name);
```

It seems to be so simple, but I fail. What I found so far is, that after

```
npm install sget
```

I can run app.js in integrated terminal and it will work interactively. But that ignores my breakpoints.

So, how can I work with readline-functionality and breakpoints set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340968/debugging-node-js-with-node-inspector

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but it doesn't seem to be the solution that I need. @Aᴍɪʀ

Comment: I know, I just wanted to give you some direction about debugging nodejs projects :)

Comment: Try debugging using Visual Studio Code or Webstorm. In those you can manipulate value of variable while in breaked condition and then continue execution with the new value and While the breakpoint is hit all the execution of all asynchronous code will be paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over to these documentations :

- https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html
- https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

these might help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do that because Node is nonblocking.

You can use Node Debugger:

- https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

or Node Inspector:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector

You can use Chrome Developer Tools to debug Node, see:

- https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27