# Easy Way to Run&debug Node.js Projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I'm using Gulp for debugging in vs code,

```
gulpfile.js
[14:32:18] Starting 'scripts'...
[14:32:20] Finished 'scripts' after 1.89 s
```

My Question is:
Easy Way to Run&debug Node.js Projects? *I will Want to Get **more error detail** or Solution*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find a Good PlayGround for Node.js, for Run & Debug realtime,
mix of babel transpiler and nodemon realtime Monitor for any changes in your node.js Files.

Answer (score -1):

Try node-inspector. There is a StackOver link that contains a link to a YouTube video on using it: [debugging node.js with node-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340968/debugging-node-js-with-node-inspector)

It is installed with the command:
$ npm install -g node-inspector

Comment: Can You Tell Me this is a Core module or no? what is pro way

Comment: sometimes we use unicorns and rainbows, sorry I could help by being sarcastic.. node-inspector is a nice utility for debugging, what kind of debugging are looking for ? like debugging the V8 engine internals .. this goes beyond the scope of debugging NodeJS applications.

Comment: I'm Developing Tree (data structure) Telegram Bot with 1000 Deep nested node

Comment: Thank you But need better awnser, for example compare some play ground like babel and ...